# Prove that $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

I have to prove that
$$
I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}
$$

I know that

$$ I_{+}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\log(2)
$$
and I can write
$$
I= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx
$$

So I have only to evaluate $$I_{-}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx
$$ 
Using the expansion of the logarithm valid in the range of integration I can also write 
$$I_{-}=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}dx
$$
but then I can go any further because I can't find a simple solution that depend only on $n$ for the rational (and solvable) integral under the sum sign .

Maybe is simple to considerate instead of $ I_{-} $ the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=I$ because it seems to me that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}dx= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{2k+1} + \frac{\pi}{4}(-1)^n)$ but again I can go further.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It might help you: $$\frac{x^n}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^n+x^{n-2}-x^{n-2}}{x^2+1}=x^{n-2}-\frac{x^{n-2}}{x^2+1}$$ With this, you can reduce all of the integrands either to $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ or to $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ plus some polynomials.

Comment: BTW, the sum is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: You should have:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2\color{red}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$I_+=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2\ ;\quad I_-=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$I_--I_+=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\overset{(1-x)/(1+x)=t}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 t^{2n}\ln tdt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+\color{red}{1}}}{(2n+1)^2}=-G$$
$$\Rightarrow I_-=I_++I_--I_+=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2-G$$
Where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: How did you know that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}dx\overset{(1-x)/(1+x)=t}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 t^{2n}\ln t~dt$$

For the first equality, substituting $t=\frac{1-x}{1+x} \implies x = \frac{1-t}{t+1} \implies dx = -\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}~dt$ forms

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{1}^0 \frac{\ln(t)}{1+\Big(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\Big)^2}\Big(\frac{-2}{(1+t)^2}\Big)dt$$

Maybe I did $dx$ wrong, I don't see how you found the second equality. I'm not sure what you did in the third equality.

Comment: For the second equality note that the minus sign that you got there changes the bounds: $\int_a^b f(x)dx=-\int_b^a f(x) dx$. Also:
$$\frac{1}{\frac{(1+t)^2+(1-t)^2}{(1+t)^2}}\frac{2}{(1+t)^2} =\frac{1}{1+t^2}$$
For the third equality just use the geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2)^{n}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand those two equalities. Then, at the last step, you have that

$$\int_0^1 t^{2n}\ln tdt=\frac{-1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

which follows from integration by parts (unless there is an easier way). After that, you get Catalan's constant.

Comment: Integration by parts is a way. However I do as follows:
$$\int_0^1 x^q dx=\frac{1}{q+1} $$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dq} \int_0^1 x^q dx=\int_0^1 x^q \ln x dx= \frac{d}{dq} \frac{1}{q+1}=-\frac{1}{(q+1)^2}$$
And now set $q=2n$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\ dx\overset{x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln2-\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2-\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2-\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy+\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy}_{\large y\mapsto 1/y}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)-\ln y}{1+y^2}\ dy\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy+\int_0^1\frac{\ln y}{1+y^2}\ dy\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2-2\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\ln2\right)-G\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln2-G
\end{align}

.

---

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy&\overset{y=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}{=}\int_0^1\frac{\ln2-\ln(1+u)}{1+u^2}\ du\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln2-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+u)}{1+u^2}\ du\\
2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy&=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln2\\
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}\ dy&=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln2
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Different method using harmonic series

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\ dx&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\int_0^1x^{2n}\ln(1-x)\ dx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
&=-\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^n H_n}{n}=-\Im\left(\frac12\ln^2(1-i)+\operatorname{Li}_2(i)\right)=\frac{\pi}{8}\ln2-G
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is to use Feynman's trick of differentiating under the integral sign. Let
$$I(a) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\ln (1 + ax)}{1 + x^2} \, dx.$$
Note that $I(0) = 0$ and we require $I(1)$. Now
\begin{align}
I'(a) &= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{(1 + ax)(1 + x^2)} \, dx\\
&= \frac{a}{1 + a^2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} + \frac{1}{1 + a^2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{1 + x^2} \, dx - \frac{a}{1 - a^2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{1 + ax}\\
&= \frac{\pi a}{2(1 + a^2)} + \frac{1}{1 + a^2} \ln \left (\frac{1 - a}{1 + a} \right )
\end{align} 
Thus
\begin{align}
I(1) &= \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{2a}{1 + a^2} \, da + \underbrace{\int_0^1 \ln \left (\frac{1 - a}{1 + a} \right ) \frac{da}{1 + a^2}}_{a \, \mapsto \, (1 - a)/(1 + a)}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln a}{1 + a^2} \, da\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 a^{2n} \ln x \, da\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{d}{ds} \left [\int_0^1 a^{2n + s} \, da \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{d}{ds} \left [\frac{1}{2n + s + 1} \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1)^2}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 - \mathbf{G}
\end{align}